# Add dynamic Sitemap to footer

Tags: menus, footer, sitemap

I'm trying to create a footer menu/sitemap of sorts in Wordpress. (It's also worth a mention this is my fist attempt at anything Wordpress/PHP related.

**Context:**

We're making use of a template called [Jupiter](http://demos.artbees.net/jupiter/), which in turn makes used of a style of WYSIWYG editor to construct the layout

> On the footer of the page, I'd like to add something to this effect. (This was our old footer)
>
> [image]

The (my) requirement is that I make use of the Wordpress menu structure so that our marketing department can alter the footer as they need to eventually without any (trickier) changes (EG. via the menu GUI editor.)

I've managed to add the menu (via dragging it onto a footer widget), but there seems to be something that causing the  newly created footer to act like an accordion. (EG. `ul` & `li`'s are expanding and collapsing)

> Hovering on the first menu node causes the accordion effect.
>
> [image]

**Questions:**

1. Is this the best way of attempting to add a sitemap, or is the fact that I'm using a menu the reason why I'm struggling. If so whats the alternative? (Hard-coding is not going to happen).
2. My thinking so far is I need to add some JavaScript & CSS to try and nullify whatever is causing the collapse, and then attempt to style it. Where would be the best place to add said code?

(I don't have any code samples yet because I'm still investigating if this can be done via the admin portal at all)

Comment: I've just asked this question on the main SO site. But only just now realized it might be better suited here. I'll remove the question that gets the first hit as I'm not sure how active this specific community is...

Comment: You could just call the menu with wp_nav_menu(); instead of using a widget, this would probably remove the javascript actions.
or you could do something like $('.menu-sitemap-container li').off("**"); in your theme's script.js. This will remove all listeners on thoses elements. But I recommend the first solution ^^

Comment: Thank you. Ill look into it. I currently have 3 menu's... how will wp_nav_menu() know which menu to reference, and secondly, where would I call that function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call wp_nav_menu() in your footer.php template.

It's used as following :

```
 <?php wp_nav_menu( array('theme_location'=>'footer') ); ?>
```

The theme_location parameters refers to the checkboxes below the menu editor (Theme location). If your theme doesn't have enough theme_location, you can add some by adding

```
function register_html5_menu(){
     register_nav_menus(array( 
         'footer-1' => __('Footer Menu 1', 'theme_translation_domain'),
     ));
}

add_action('init', 'register_html5_menu');
```

in your functions.php

Otherwise you can call the menus directly by their names using the menu parameter :

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array('menu'=>'menuname') ); ?>
```